# Doctrine 2 ManyToMany Saving but not fetching

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Entity Class for the Company this is how I declared addresses:

```
/**
 * The addresses the company has had. The one with the newest create date
 * is the current address.
 *
 * Mapped as many to many with a unique constraint to force the one to
 * many relationship:
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fp_company_addresses",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *     )
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection Collection of addresses
 */
private $addresses;
```

When We save the Company Details in the Company Form, the Addresses is being saved in the database, but when we want to get the list of Companies like this:

```
$companies = $this->getRepo('AppBundle:Company')->findAll();
```

We are getting an empty array for addresses even though we have it in the Database.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What happens when you try [validate schema](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#runtime-vs-development-mapping-validation) via console?

Comment: $ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.```
```[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.```

Comment: How does look inverse side property in `Address` entity?

Comment: Did you perform a simple `var_dump($companies)` to check for the empty address array ... or did you call `Company::getAdresses` ?  This looks like a lazy-loading issue.

Comment: @TomášVotruba It is unidirectional so there is no inverse side

Comment: @nifr We actually called the getAddresses, we did not just dump the addresses property